# What is smalltalk's sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smalltalk, seaside

I've seen on the web several comparsions of 
(Smalltalk + Seaside) VS (Ruby + Rails)

But I'm wondering if Seaside is comparable to Rails.
What is the equivalent of Sinatra?

What is smalltalk's web microframework?

Is there one? Seaside can work on both ways? Could Iliad be compared?

Answer (score 2):

There are several web servers and micro web microframework available that are comparable to Sinatra: [Zinc](http://zn.stfx.eu/zn/index.html), [WebServer](http://www.squeaksource.com/KomHttpServer.html), [Kom](http://www.squeaksource.com/KomHttpServer.html) and [Swazoo](http://www.swazoo.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[RatPack](https://github.com/timfel/ratpack) by Tim Felgentreff is just exactly ment to provide Sintara conecpts for Smalltalk.
Tim knows Sinatra very well and modeled RatPack a bit like that.

Answer (score 1):

All main Smalltalk web frameworks ([Seaside](http://www.seaside.st), [Aida](http://www.aidaweb.si), [Iliad](http://www.iliadproject.org) and client-side [Amber](http://amber-lang.net)) don't cover persistence and don't use templating, those are major differences to frameworks like Ruby on Rails. For comparison (and maybe for answering to your question) you can look at [comparison of Aida, Seaside and Iliad](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Atnb1W9vuq9ndGRTUFIzT3VON0lTQ3JxdlZYTUxhOFE&hl=en&authkey=CJva7-8L&pli=1#gid=0).

Comment: GemStone's Seaside framework (GLASS) provides transparent persistence. See [Seaside.GemStone.com](http://seaside.gemstone.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Colin Putney's Altitude is another lightweight web framework: 
[announcement on squeak-dev mailing list](http://forum.world.st/ANN-Altitude-td4640421.html)